# How to slowdown an output character by character? (Mac OS)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

My goal is to output a string of characters one by one. But when I run it, it staggers and ends up just outputting the entire string with no delay in-between characters. I am currently running this code on a Mac operating system.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

/**
    Asks user to input name.
    @param usrName Displays the the prompt asking for their name.
*/
void displaySequence(std::string usrName);

int main() {
    std::string prompt = "Name: ";
    std::string clientName;

    displaySequence(prompt);
    std::cin >> clientName;
    

    return 0;
}

void displaySequence(std::string usrName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) usrName.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << usrName.at(i) << " ";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    }
}
```

Comment: 20 milliseconds is a very short delay. 50 characters per second. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output to `std::cout` is usually line-buffered - that is to say, it is only sent to the terminal when a newline is encountered (or the buffer fills up).

You can modify this behaviour with [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush):

```
std::cout << usrName.at(i) << " " << std::flush;
```

Any buffered output will then be written to the terminal immediately.